# "Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt." on windows7 professional

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, installation

f I want to start ***grunt***, I get the following message:

```
c:\repositories\kunde_1\themes-projekt_1\projekt_1-responsive\source>grunt
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

When running grunt you will see:

```
C:\Users\dev_user>npm install -g grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/findup-sync
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
C:\Users\dev_user\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt -> C:\Users\dev_user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 C:\Users\dev_user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli
+-- nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7)
+-- resolve@0.3.1
+-- findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)
```

Entering grunt in user directory:

```
C:\Users\dev_user>grunt
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)

Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt
hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about
installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

But the same message comes when I enter the project directory!

> operating system: windows 7 Professional
>   npm -version: 1.3.5  
>   node --version: v0.10.15

```
C:\Users\dev_user>npm ls -g
C:\Users\dev_user\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- coffee-script@1.9.3
+-- grunt-cli@0.1.13
  +-- findup-sync@0.1.3
  ¦ +-- glob@3.2.11
  ¦ ¦ +-- inherits@2.0.1
  ¦ ¦ +-- minimatch@0.3.0
  ¦ ¦   +-- lru-cache@2.6.5
  ¦ ¦   +-- sigmund@1.0.1
  ¦ +-- lodash@2.4.2
  +-- nopt@1.0.10
  ¦ +-- abbrev@1.0.7
  +-- resolve@0.3.1
```

The environment variable I have set:

Name of variable: **grunt**
Path: `C:\Users\dev_user\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt`
then launched new computer

Does anyone have an idea why the message *Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.* coming?

Answer (score 5):

Installing `grunt-cli` does not install the Grunt task runner. `grunt-cli` is Command line interface that allows multiple versions of Grunt to be installed on the same machine simultaneously.

To install `grunt` you need to install it globally by the following command:

```
npm install -g grunt
```

or locally by the following command:

```
npm install grunt
```

You cold read about `grunt-cli` in [official doc](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#how-the-cli-works)

Note from @Matthew Bakaitis:

> Installing grunt globally is discouraged
>
> It's good practice as grunt-cli loads a global version first (if I recall). If a project was expecting a specific version of grunt, installing globally would break this. Also, if you are depending upon grunt for your builds, why wouldn't you install it as a dependency and list it in package.json? There's a huge assumption that other developers or the target system will have grunt installed globally if you aren't adding as a dependency in package.json. Given the usage situations for grunt, I can't think of many situations where a global install would be better.

Comment: FYI: Installing `grunt` globally is [discouraged](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-the-cli).

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis could you explain why please?

Comment: It's good practice as `grunt-cli` loads a global version first (if I recall). If a project was expecting a specific version of grunt, installing globally would break this.  Also, if you are depending upon grunt for your builds, why wouldn't you install it as a dependency and list it in `package.json`?  There's a huge assumption that other developers or the target system will have grunt installed globally if you aren't adding as a dependency in `package.json`.  Given the usage situations for grunt, I can't think of many situations where a global install would be better.

Comment: Thanks. I've added your note to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem.
In my case I have a co-worker found the solution.
I had installed two version of NodeJS, an older 1.0.35 and the current 1.2.7 version.
In Windows uninstaller only one version was visible!
After I have uninstalled that version and all directories, that is, the old version and the new version was deleted after the current version was contradicted installed, because I could command should ***npm install*** call.
After that, I can grunt call easily, it is working properly.